# Text Messaging Dots

Tags: iphone

If I sent 2 text messages to 2 different people within a few minutes of each other and returned to one of those conversations and saw the dot bubbles like I was getting a response, and then received an actual response to the other message (the one I wasn't looking at), would that mean that the dot bubbles were for the other conversation and not the one I was looking at when I saw them?

Answer (score 1):

No, the typing indicator is specific to the person that is typing the message. The typing indicator will be shown in the conversation that it is relevant to.

Comment: The dots also don't necessarily mean they're actually typing, only that the text entry area has been recently activated, as can happen if they are merely reading your message.

Comment: @Tetsujin Activating the text area doesn't show the dots—this is something I tested at one point. It only shows once characters have been typed.

Comment: Hmmm... OK, something I've always assumed, based on my partner 's reply habits, but never tested empirically.

Comment: Tested - agreed. I guess she just spends a lot of time starting a reply, then changing her mind ;)